# Sqlite Database error column error

Tags: sqlite

When I try to insert values in my table in complains that ContactInfo Column. It says it does not exist. This problem start when I updated my database schemmas. I have tried to check what the problem is in the query But I dont seem to find any error.

```
    public final static String HOSPITAL_TABLE="Hospital";

    public final static String HID ="ID";

    public final static String HOSPITALID = "HospitalID";

    public final static String HOSPITAL_NAME ="Name";

    public final static String HOSPITAL_HotLine = "HotLine";

    public final static String HOSPITAL_ContactLine = "ContactLine";

    public final static String HOSPITAL_Email = "Email";


public static final String CREATE_HOSPITAL_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+HOSPITAL_TABLE+" ( "+HID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+HOSPITALID+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_NAME+", TEXT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_Email+" TEXT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_HotLine+" TEXT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_ContactLine+"TEXT NULL "+" )";
```

Comment: `ContactInfo` column? I can't find it on the code you shared... Is it supposed to be there?

Comment: missed a space at `"TEXT` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is here

```
public static final String CREATE_HOSPITAL_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+HOSPITAL_TABLE+" ( "+HID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+HOSPITALID+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_NAME+", TEXT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_Email+" TEXT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_HotLine+" TEXT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_ContactLine+"TEXT NULL "+" )";
```

You have kept extra comma after hospital name and did not give space after HOSPITAL_ContactLine. So change above line to

```
public static final String CREATE_HOSPITAL_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+HOSPITAL_TABLE+" ( "+HID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+HOSPITALID+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_NAME+" TEXT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_Email+" TEXT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_HotLine+" TEXT NULL, "+HOSPITAL_ContactLine+" TEXT NULL "+" )";
```